# Web api 2 Controller whit action, using entity framework no return json

Tags: c#, json, controller, asp.net-web-api

I generate a Web Api controller from table "Equipo" but no return Json only works with views or tables without dependencies from other table. I tried with this code in `WebApiConfig`:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
```

But isnt result I want. I want only simple Json with data from table "Equipo"

```sql
CREATE TABLE Equipo(
  idEquipo INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  nombre VARCHAR(255),
  puntos INT ,
  partidosJugados INT,
  partidosGanados INT,
  partidosPerdidos INT,
  partidosEmpatados INT,
  golesAFavor INT,
  goleEnContra INT,
PRIMARY KEY(idEquipo)
);
```

The controller using "http://localhost:53054/api/Equipo" is:

> An exception has occurred while using the formatter 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' to generate sample for media type 'application/json'. Exception message: Se han producido uno o varios errores.

Comment: You better use DTO's in such case to avoid the overhead of referencelooping